# How to run only one test file using Selenium webdriver and mocha?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

I have several files in the test folder.
[Test files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2dQs.png)
Each file has several test suites and test cases. `npm test` command runs all the files one after another. How do I run just one test file?

I tried `npm test -- --grep "file name"` command, but it didn't work. This command only works with the name of the test suites or test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a test script defined in your package.json file like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "test":{command to run tests}
}
```

Modify the test script to include the path to the specific test file you want to run like following:

```
"scripts": {
  "test":{command to run tests} test/myTestFile.js
}
```

Now try running **npm test** command. Hope this helps!!!